# multiple targets build in makefile

Tags: makefile

Any idea why something like this wouldnt work in makefile ?

```
all : $(GOAL_DB) $(GOAL)

%.d: %.cpp      
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS_DB) $<  > $@
%.o : %.cpp
    $(CC) $(FLAGS_DB) $< -o $@

$(GOAL_DB) : $(OFILES)
        $(CC) $(LFLAGS_DB) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS_DB)
    strip $(GOAL_DB)
    rm -f *.o *.d

%.d: %.cpp     
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $<  > $@
%.o : %.cpp
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $< -o $@
$(GOAL) : $(OFILES)
        $(CC) $(LFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)
    strip $(GOAL)
    rm -f *.o *.d
```

I'm just trying to build two different targets using make all , GNU make.

The first target builds fine , but it not creating new objects files for another target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A makefile is not like a standard program that is executed sequentially. It seems you've made the assumption that new rules appearing before a new target will apply to that target. This is not the case. The makefile is fully evaluated for variables, targets, dependencies, and more, before it starts applying rules.

Make is going to match those $(OFILES) against only one of those %.d: targets, probably the first target pattern it finds.

The reason you are not getting new objects for the other target is that to make it looks like you are building the same set of files twice, thus skipping the second build because it's already complete.

A solution is to use 'target specific variables':

```
all : $(GOAL_DB) $(GOAL)

$(GOAL): BUILD_FLAGS=$(FLAGS)
$(GOAL): BUILD_CPPFLAGS=$(CPPFLAGS)
$(GOAL): BUILD_OUTDIR=./outdir
$(GOAL): $(OFILES)

$(GOAL_DB): BUILD_FLAGS=$(FLAGS_DB)
$(GOAL_DB): BUILD_CPPFLAGS=$(CPPFLAGS_DB)
$(GOAL_DB): BUILD_OUTDIR=./outdir_db
$(GOAL_DB): $(OFILES)

%.d: %.cpp      
    mkdir -p $(BUILD_OUTDIR)
    $(CC) $(BUILD_CPPFLAGS) $<  > $(BUILD_OUTDIR)/$@

%.o : %.cpp
    mkdir -p $(BUILD_OUTDIR)
    $(CC) $(BUILD_FLAGS) $< -o $(BUILD_OUTDIR)/$@
```

Comment: Thanks! yes i assumed a sequential execution which is definitely not happening. Your solution make so much more sense, but it doesn't create two targets upon make all.

Comment: It still doesnt create the object files for another one. Im trying to build the same set of files but its using different libraries , you think that could be a problem ?

Comment: Ah right. The output files are still the same. The makefile should probably be setup to output to separate directories.

Comment: Added output dir variable.